# Controlling where a figure appears

Tags: graphics, floats

I want to insert an image immediately below the semicolon in the following:

The sequent calculus proof of this uses contraction and is therefore not derivable in linear logic (unless special modalities are used):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   

\begin{document} 
  The sequent calculus proof of this uses contraction and is therefore not derivable in linear logic (unless special modalities are used):
\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics[width=10cm,scale=18]{prooftreeseqmg2.pdf}
\centering
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

At the moment the image does not appear directly below my text. How can I change this?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text

Comment: With `[t]` it will appear at the top of a page. `\centering` *after* the graphic doesn't really make sense if you want to have the graphic centered.